# Why fallback function cannot be declared public in solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.6.x

When declaring fallback function we needs to make sure that it is declared `external` but why fallback function cannot be declared as `public`. Since `external` is a subset of `public` why can't we declare the fallback function public.

Viewing from the perspective of definition of `external`(**Only accessible externally not internally**). Why do use external in fallback?

Comment: Because there is obviously no reason to call it internally.

Comment: @goodvibration why not public?

Comment: Because there is obviously no reason to call it internally (let me know if you want me to repeat that again).

Comment: @goodvibration my bad. Understand it now

Comment: The answer below explains it quite well (why there is obviously no reason to call it internally). You may wanna read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.11/contracts.html):

> A contract can have at most one `fallback` function, declared using `fallback () external [payable]` (without the `function` keyword). This function cannot have arguments, cannot return anything and must have `external` visibility. It is executed on a call to the contract if none of the other functions match the given function signature, or if no data was supplied at all and there is no receive Ether function. The fallback function always receives data, but in order to also receive Ether it must be marked `payable`.

There's no real purpose for calling it internally, since it cannot have any arguments and cannot return anything. For that reason, it must be declared as `external`.